# Why is stack.head prefix required to access local context in Dust.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

I have a strange issue with Dust.js contexts. Previously, I would pass the view model along as a plain old JavaScript object, e.g. `res.render('page', { something: [1,2,3] }` etc. When doing that, I could access `something` on the local context with `{#something}...{/something}` etc.

However, I changed the way I manage the context to use `dust.makeBase`, so that I can have globals and some sort of stack, rather than just an object. I'm using `consolidate` with `express` FWIW.

Now, I create the baseViewModel.

```
//
// at application init
//
app.baseViewModel = dust.makeBase({
  someGlobal: 'example'
})
```

Later on, when rendering, I may extend it like so:

```
// 
// in route handler
//
const viewModel = app.baseViewModel.push({
  collection: someCollection
})

res.render('index', viewModel)
```

But then, the context stack looks like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    // snip
  },
  "stack": {
    "isObject": true,
    "head": {
      "collection": [
        // snip
      ]
    }
  },
  "global": {
    "someGlobal": "example"
  }
}
```

The problem is, now, to access collection, I must prefix the variables with `stack.head.`:

```
{#stack.head.collection}
  <!-- etc -->
{/stack.head.collection}
```

Does anyone know why this is, and how I can get back to the simple way of just referring to `{#collection}` etc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, but it's a hack and should have to be done this way. There is a GitHub ticket now for this issue:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/issues/743

Anyway, this is what I did:

```
dust.helpers.collection = (chunk, context, bodies, params) => {
  return context.current().get('collection')
}
```

And then modified my markup to:

```
{@collection}
  {.Name} etc
{/collection}
```

Strange, but I guess that's the way it works!

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any of this-- `head` is just the internal representation of the context stack, and Dust will traverse it natively for you.

Comment: I understand that, but it doesn't seem to work. As soon as I moved away from POJOs to a dust context object (for globals), I lost the ability to do that. Any idea why that might be? I think it might have something to do with `consolidate`.

Comment: How does your use case differ from the example I linked? The example is also using a Dust context object.

Comment: I would say the only difference I can see is that I'm rendering server-side with [consolidate](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/lib/consolidate.js#L353-L391).

Comment: OK, here's what I suspect to be happening-- `Context#wrap` checks if your context is an `instanceof Context`, and I'll bet that consolidate loads a different? Dust than you're loading to build your Context in your application. That makes the `instanceof` check fail, and your Context gets double-wrapped, so to speak.

Comment: I put together an example of a working app here: https://github.com/adamkdean/dust-test

Comment: That makes absolute sense actually. I brought in the dustjs-linkedin module to create the context because I couldn't find that method on the consolidate version. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, consolidate tries `engine = requires.dust = require('dust');` first.

Comment: Hm. Consolidate loads `dustjs-helpers` as the dust engine, but using that to create the context still doesn't help the situation. Nor does making consolidate use `dustjs-linkedin`.

Comment: Look into this further, it looks like when I pass in the context, things are getting added to it as it becomes the "options" object [see here](https://gist.github.com/adamkdean/14bc1f9958be34eb54622f74e5ca09a8) so this is definitely an issue with consolidate.

Comment: If you're not wed to consolidate we have an example in the repo using [hoffman](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/tree/master/examples/streaming-hoffman)

Comment: The marriage has been frustrating and unenjoyable. Luckily, I'm not so far into this project that it's a divorce, more of an annulment. Will elope with hoffman. Thanks again for your help, top notch!

Comment: Hmm. Even with hoffman this is happening. I think `express` might be adding items onto the options and passing it along.

Comment: Where are you deriving "options" from? A context object is a standalone thing. Are you piping them through Express somehow?

Comment: I would expect you to be calling something like `res.render` or `res.stream` as `res.render(tmpl, contextObject)`, where the `contextObject` is something that you just created via `dust.context` and `context.push`

Comment: Correct, calling res.render('template', context). But for some reason, the item that gets passed through seems to mutate.

Comment: I've put together a really quick example using hoffman and contexts, which shows that POJOs render but Contexts do not. https://github.com/adamkdean/dust-test/blob/master/index.js

Comment: So it goes through this function (https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L937) which adds a lot of gubbins onto the object. I think this may be what is causing the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123073/discussion-between-adam-k-dean-and-interrobang).

Comment: I've put in a GH ticket here: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/issues/743

Comment: Only just seen your response below. Thanks for the PR.

Answer (score 0):

As per our comment chain, here's what I suspect to be the issue.

When you create a new Context object in Dust, it [checks to see if you're passing in an existing Context to hydrate from](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/v2.7.3/lib/dust.js#L338). This is done using an `instanceof` check.

If the object does not seem to be an instance of a Context, it gets wrapped in a new Context, which would account for the behavior you're seeing here. This isn't great, so I'll go work on a PR to use a flag instead of an `instanceof` check.

You're using consolidate, which includes a dependency on dust, and I suspect that the version it includes is different than whatever you depend on in your package.json. I would check to see how many copies of `dustjs-linkedin` are in your tree (one in your root and one in consolidate's node_modules, perhaps). If you require `dustjs-helpers` it simply requires `dustjs-linkedin` itself, so the latter is what you really care about.

Comment: Only just seen this response. Was focused on the comment chain above. As per that, I created a GH issue at https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/issues/743 with all relevant information in it. Again, thanks for the help. Appreciated. FWIW, moved to Hoffman with same results.